# Rails wizard form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, erb

I have an enrollment form where a user can enroll to some sort of event.

However, I want to give the posibility for teams to enroll also and I was thinking about a wizard like form.

Basically create 5 records at a time.

The problem is, I'll have a new enrollment creation on each step, so I thought the `wicked` gem would not do it for this scenario.

Can you give me a few guidelines on how should I approach this?

Maybe just render `new` after creation if a `i.e. team` attr is sent from the form?

Maybe use self join?

That's off the top of my head but I know there has to be a clever way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how your models are structured, but if you have something like:

```
class Attendee
  has_many :enrolments
  has_many :events, through: :enrolments
end

class Enrolment
  has_many :attendees
  belongs_to :event
end

class Event
  has_many :enrolments
  has_many :attendees, through: :enrolments
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :enrolments
end
```

Then you can do something like:

```
# controllers/enrolments_controller.rb
class EnrolmentController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
    pax = params[:persons].to_i
    pax.times do
      @event.enrolments.build
    end
  end

  def create
    @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
    @event.enrolments.build(enrolment_params)
    @event.save
  end

protected
  def enrolment_params
    # require specific parameters here
    params.require(:event).permit(:attendee_attributes => [])
  end
end

# views/enrolments/new.html.erb
<%= form_for @event, url: event_enrolments_path(@event) do |f| %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :event_id %>
  <%= f.fields_for :enrolments do |af| %>
    <%= af.select :attendee_id, Attendee.all.collect {|p| [ p.name, p.id ] } %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>

# routes.rb
resources :events do
  resources :enrolments
end
```

That's off the top of my head, but the general idea is that you build the nested fields by running event.enrolments.build based on the number of people passed in the params.

This uses [fields_for](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-fields_for) and accepts_nested_attributes_for. This also makes it really convenient to reuse existing forms by passing in the form context in the partial:

```
<%= f.fields_for :enrolments do |af| %>
  <%= render "enrolments/form", f: af %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Hey man, thanks for the idea. Right now, I just have an enrollment form, which holds an atendee's information and an event_id (edition). Basically just 2 models related here, an event and an enrollment model.